# Injecting a module into angular as module not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, bower

I can't seem to inject a module into my angular app.

I am trying to import the following module which is installed through bower using:

```
bower install angular-pagedown --save
```

This seems to load fine within the bower-components folder which is in the following folder structure:

```
clinet
------app
---------bower-components
-------------------angular-pagedown
-------------------pagedown
```

When I try inject the module as it says in the instructions using 'ui.pagedown' which is indeed the name of the module, I use the following code in app.js:

```
import _Auth from '../components/auth/auth.module';
import account from './account';
import admin from './admin';
import navbar from '../components/navbar/navbar.component';
import footer from '../components/footer/footer.component';
import main from './main/main.component';
import questionsCreate from 
'./questionsCreate/questionsCreate.component';
import questionsShow from './questionsShow/questionsShow.component';
import constants from './app.constants';
import util from '../components/util/util.module';
import socket from '../components/socket/socket.service';


import './app.scss';

angular.module('filQuestionsApp', [ngCookies, ngResource, ngSanitize, 
'btford.socket-io', uiRouter,
  uiBootstrap, _Auth, account, admin, 'validation.match', navbar, 
footer, main, questionsCreate,
  questionsShow, constants, socket, util, 'ui.pagedown'
])
```

I seem to get the following error when trying to use the module:

> Module 'ui.pagedown' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I seem to be doing something really wrong with bower and angular together, I'm also getting `400 errors` in terms of formatting and I'm not sure on the injection process.

Comment: Are you loading that library? If not, the dependency injector won't work.

Comment: Sorry to be naive but what do you mean by "loading" the module. This is most likely then it I'm missing.

Comment: Not sure about those imports you have there, but normally what I did with AngularJS is to load the modules/libraries in the html with a script tag, hence the DI is able to resolve them. You can even use a module loader like systemjs, that's why I was asking how you are loading them.

Comment: This was actually the answer so I'm using gulp and it's not placing the bower js files in my HTML hence they are indeed not being loaded. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How `angular-pagedown` work:

```
bower install angular-pagedown --save
```

This will also install pagedown dependencies.
Import these files in your HTML:

```
pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js
pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer.js
pagedown/Markdown.Extra.js
pagedown/Markdown.Editor.js
angular-pagedown/angular-pagedown.js
angular-pagedown/angular-pagedown.css
```

If you're using a build tool like grunt/gulp's main-bower-files, you don't need to import the files manually.
But add this in your `bower.json`

```
"overrides": {
  "pagedown": {
    "main": [
      "Markdown.Converter.js",
      "Markdown.Sanitizer.js",
      "Markdown.Extra.js",
      "Markdown.Editor.js",
      "wmd-buttons.png"
    ]
  }
}
```

Include dependency in your app `angular.module("yourApp", ["ui.pagedown"]);`

Comment: Thank you! These are the exact steps I followed. I have the pagedown dependency too. I am using gulp and have done what you have said here. Not sure why it's still not working.

Comment: Since you are using gulp, have you changed your bower.json? Check out the spellings too

Comment: Also loading the directory means including its reference/script in your html